# VLSM: Any easy way to learn it

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

After my first year at university our teachers decided to make VLSM exams and exercises a bit harder. For exactly 1 year ago we got 3-4 hours to subnet using VLSM and then start with Packet Tracer challenges. Nowadays we have only 2 hours and our teachers expect us to do subnetting in 20-30 mins. My main problem is that I find it very hard to understand VLSM subnetting. I have no problems finding subnet mask, [using this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt0RQX3QCO8&feature=youtu.be), but I wounder if there is any simple way to understand how I split any network for different subnets? For **example**:

Network: XXX.XX.0.0/21

- up link 1  (1 device)
- up link 2  (1 device)
- VLAN 10    (59 devices)
- VLAN 20    (196 devices)
- VLAN 30    (927 devices)
- VLAN 50    (389 devices)

On exams I'm allowed to use only pen and paper and results should include network address, subnet mask, first, last usable and broadcast addresses.  I'm looking for **easy way to understand it**, something like in video I linked above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to understand it quite well is doing lots of exercises. But to summarize, there are a few concepts:

- In practice, there are 3 IP address types (A, B and C). Each of them have their base netmask, which you can subnet afterwards. For IP addresses of type A, netmask is `255.0.0.0`, and the private addresses are in the format `10.0.0.0` to `10.255.255.255`. For B class, the netmask is `255.255.0.0` and the private addresses go from `172.16.0.0` to `172.31.0.0`. And for class C, the base netmask is `255.255.255.0` and the base IP address goes from `192.168.0.0 to`192.168.255.0`. You have more info [here](http://www.vlsm-calc.net/ipclasses.php).
- On the netmask, you have to be aware how much zeros you have and how many ones. The zeros represent number of *nets* that you have, while the zeros represent the number of hosts that can have each of the nets.

A very common question in this kind of exams are in the form:

> What is the minimal netmask that should be used for a subnet to have 10 hosts on it, using class C private adresses?

It's important that to know that, you need to apply the `2^n - 2` formula, where `n` are the bits of the host, to know how much hosts you can have within a subnet. The `- 2` part is because there are two IP addresses that are not usable: the net address (the first one) and the broadcast address (the last one).

So as said, class C addresses have their netmask in this form: `255.255.255.0`. In binary, that is written that way:

`11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000`

If you don't know how to pass a decimal number to binary, have a look [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary).

On that binary subnet mask, let's center on the zeros as we said we're seeking the number of **hosts*.

- What would happen if we take 1 zero bit? We would have `2^1 - 2 = 0`, which is less than the 10 requested hosts. It's not enough.
- What would happen if we take 2 zero bits? We would have `2^2 - 2 = 2`, which is less than the 10 requested hosts. It's not enough.
- What would happen if we take 3 zero bits? We would have `2^3 - 2 = 6`, which is less than the 10 requested hosts. It's not enough.
- What would happen if we take 4 zero bits? We would have `2^4 - 2 = 14`, which is more than 10. It's enough!

The question asks for the minimal subnet mask, so from the last operation we now know that we need *only 4 zero bytes* (remember, zeros represent the number of hosts). In practice that means that the netmask would be:

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.11110000
```

Synonyms for this netmask are:

- `/28`
- `255.255.255.240`

Look that you have four ones as well. That means that you can have: `2^4 = 16` nets. So starting with `192.168.1.0` (I'm taking `.1.` as the third octet, but you could take any other), the 16 nets would be (divide `256` between the number of nets):

- `192.168.1.0 - 15`
- `192.168.1.16 - 31`
- `192.168.1.32 - 45`
  ...

What are the network and broadcast addresses of each of these subnets? The first and last, respectively:

- Network address for the first subnet: `192.168.1.0`
- Network address for the second subnet: `192.168.1.16`
- ...
- Broadcast address for the first subnet: `192.168.1.15`
- Broadcast address for the second subnet: `192.168.1.31`
- ...

This is just one exercise but in essence it's the base of any other. There are a few more useful links which explain this subject in deep, but remember, the secret is doing lots and lots of exercises and this way you'll acquire the needed knowledge to do anything.

- [How to subnet a network](http://www.bradreese.com/how-to-subnet-a-network.pdf)
- [How to subnet](http://www.subnetting.net/Tutorial.aspx)
- [8 Steps to Understanding IP Subnetting](https://www.techopedia.com/6/28587/internet/8-steps-to-understanding-ip-subnetting)